# How can I get all site collections and sub-sites inside a PowerShell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell

I am building a PowerShell script to loop through all site collections and their sub-sites to get all users who are defined inside the related site owner group. Currently, I have this script where I need to provide each site collection URL manually, as follow:-

```
<#
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
.SYNOPSIS
  Name: Get-FullOwnerReport.ps1
  This script looks for and reports all users and groups that have full control access for all sites and subsites
  in a user's tenant

.Requirements
SPO PnP Module: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases 

.PARAMETER rootSite
  The SharePoint Online root site url

.PARAMETER outputPath
  The file path that the user wishes to contain the final report


.OUTPUTS
Exports data into a csv named FullOwnersReport.csv

  
.EXAMPLE
  .\Get-FullOwnerReport.ps1 -rootSite "https://myTenant.sharepoint.com" -outputPath "c:\temp"

#>

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    HelpMessage="Enter sharepoint root url",
    ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    $rootSite,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    HelpMessage="Enter file path to create CSV report in",
    ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Container  })]
    $outputPath
)

try
{
    Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb runas -ArgumentList "Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Force -AllowClobber;" -Wait
    Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
}

$spcred = Get-Credential

$allSubSites = @()
$urls = @()
$allGroupSites = @()

Connect-PNPonline -Url "$($rootSite)"  -UseWebLogin
$urls = Get-PnPTenantSite -Url "$rootSite"  -IncludeOneDriveSites  -Detailed

foreach($url in $urls)
{
    try
    {
       Connect-PNPonline -Url "$($url.Url)"  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -UseWebLogin
        $allSubSites += Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "Warning Access to $($url.Url) was denied."
    }
}

$allSubSites += $urls
$allOwners = @()
foreach($url in $allSubSites)
{
    try
    {
        Connect-PNPonline -Url "$($url.Url)"  -ErrorAction Stop -UseWebLogin
        $owners = Get-PnPGroup -ErrorAction Stop | where {$_.Title -match "Owners"} 
        foreach($owner in $owners)
        {

            $allOwnerGroups  = Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity "$($owner.Title)"
            Write-Host "Accessing users of group $($owner.Title)"

            foreach($lowerOwner in $allOwnerGroups)
            {
                Write-Host "User $($lowerOwner.LoginName) found as owner for site $($url.Url)"

                $object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
                $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name LoginName –Value $lowerOwner.LoginName
                $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Email –Value $lowerOwner.Email
                $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name URL –Value "$($url.Url)"

                $allOwners += $object
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "Warning Access to $($url.Url) was denied."
    }

}

$GroupReport = $outputPath + "\FullOwnersReport.csv"

if((Test-Path -Path "$GroupReport"))
{
    $allOwners  | Export-Csv -Path "$GroupReport" -Force -NoTypeInformation
}
else
{
    New-Item -Path "$GroupReport" -ItemType file
    $allOwners  | Export-Csv -Path "$GroupReport" -Force -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Can I modify the script to automatically loop through all the site collections inside our tenant and their sub-sites for getting the users inside the Site Owner group?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the below PowerShell which will fetch the Site Collections from the tenant by providing the tenant URL.

```
# Input Parameters     
$spcred = Get-Credential   
$URL = "Tenant URL"  
    
# Connect to SharePoint Online   
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $URL -UseWebLogin
  
# Get the site collections  
$siteColl = Get-PnPTenantSite  
  
# Loop through the site collections  
$allSubSites = @()
foreach($site in $siteColl)  
{  
    write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Site Collection: " $site.Url  
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url -UseWebLogin
  
    $allSubSites += Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

After fetching the sub-sites, try to execute your script for getting the users from the Site Owner group.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below PowerShell script:

```
Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

#Provide your SharePoint Online Admin center URL
$AdminSiteURL = "https://<Tenant_Name>-admin.sharepoint.com"
 
#Get SharePoint Admin User Credentials  
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
#Connect to SharePoint Admin Site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credentials $Cred 
 
#Get all site collections
$Sites = Get-PnPTenantSite
#The below command gets only modern Team & Communication sites
#$Sites = Get-PnPTenantSite | Where -Property Template -In ("GROUP#0", "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0")
   
$AllSites = @()
 
$i = 0;
$TotoalSites = $Sites.Count

#Enumerate site collections and get sub sites recursively
ForEach($Site in $Sites)
{
    $i++;
    Write-Progress -activity "Processing $($Site.Url)" -status "$i out of $TotoalSites completed"
 
    $SubWebs=$null;
    Try
    {
    
        #Connect to site collection
        $SiteConnection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -Credentials $Cred
   
        #Get the sub sites of the site collection
        $SubWebs = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -Connection $SiteConnection
  
        Disconnect-PnPOnline -Connection $SiteConnection
    }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Error occured $($Site.Url) : $_.Exception.Message"   -Foreground Red;
    }
 
    #Add site collection in AllSites list 
    $AllSites += New-Object PSObject -property $([ordered]@{ 
        SiteName  = $Site.Title            
        SiteURL = $Site.Url
        IsSubSite = $false
        HasSubSites = if ($SubWebs -and $SubWebs.Count -gt 0) { $true } Else {$false}
        SiteCollectionName = $Site.Title
        SiteCollectionURL = $Site.Url
    })
 
    if ($SubWebs -and $SubWebs.Count -gt 0) {
    
        #Enumerate sub sites and add in AllSites list 
        ForEach($SubSite in $SubWebs)
        {
            $AllSites += New-Object PSObject -property $([ordered]@{ 
            SiteName  = $SubSite.Title            
            SiteURL = $SubSite.Url
            IsSubSite = $true
            HasSubSites = $false
            SiteCollectionName = $Site.Title
            SiteCollectionURL = $Site.Url
            })
        }
    }
}

#Display all site collections and sub sites
$AllSites | Select SiteName,SiteURL,IsSubSite
#$AllSites | Export-CSV "C:\AllSites-and-SubSites.CSV" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: i do not want to simply list all site collections and subsites.. i need to list the users inside the Owner groups

Comment: You can view this case: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/713215/can-i-get-all-site-collections-and-sub-sites-insid.html